# Mac: How to fix sudo command failure?

Tags: macos

I am writing script to run SU commands programmatically to do various operations. But, All the commands created through my program is not working. Then, i tried those commands in Terminal (Mac os x) by typing it, but it gives the following result,

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Could someone please advise me, why is this error coming up, how can i make these working?

Comment: That command doesn't seem to exist on OSX. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554271/what-is-the-equivalent-of-aptitude-in-mac-osx (this provides information to install it)

Comment: apt-get isn't installed in osx, typically osx users use brew

Comment: I am trying to follow noVnc feature using this link, "http://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/screenshots.html" So in this link, they are asking to use sudo commands, for example: sudo apt-get install tightvncserver. What can i do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew installs the stuff you need that Apple didn’t. 
install `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"`

e.g :
`$ brew install wget`

Comment: I am trying to follow noVnc feature using this link, "kanaka.github.io/noVNC/screenshots.html"; So in this link, they are asking to use sudo commands, for example: sudo apt-get install tightvncserver. What can i do now?

Answer (score 1):

There's also [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), and [fink](http://finkproject.org) -- I also have homebrew, but also keep the others around for when I encounter things that one system has that the other doesn't.

Comment: I am trying to follow noVnc feature using this link, "kanaka.github.io/noVNC/screenshots.html"; So in this link, they are asking to use sudo commands, for example: sudo apt-get install tightvncserver. What can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is unique to the Debian based operating systems. If you want a package manager for OSX, may I suggest `homebrew`

http://brew.sh

Comment: I am trying to follow noVnc feature using this link, "kanaka.github.io/noVNC/screenshots.html"; So in this link, they are asking to use sudo commands, for example: sudo apt-get install tightvncserver. What can i do now?

Comment: Read the FAQ for TightVNC – unfortunately they do not support OSX at this time http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php